# Only getting a prediction 0 when using Longformer for binary text classification for long text file (9000 words)

Tags: memory, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

I am trying to do a binary text classification for patent that has an average of 9000 words in a txt file, and I am using textrank to summarize the textfile first to reduce the words count to 4096 before feeding into the Longformer model. I basically use textrank to get the top 100 or so sentences in the patent as the summary.

However, after my training, I ran prediction on the test dataset, but I am only getting 0 in the prediction. (The dataset is unbalance with about 70% False and 30% True).
How should I approach to fix the problem? Would that happend because using textrank? Would that problem be fix when I change some hyperparameters? (I have a hardtime tuning the parameters because it takes a really long time)

Because memory constrain, in my training I am only using 1000 sample rows instead of the whole 70000 rows.

Thank you for your help!!!

Example of data:
Text                Label
"some patent 1"     0
"some patent 2"     0
"some patent 3"     1
"some patent 4"     0

TextRank extract

```
    for i in range(num_sentences):
        sim_mat[i, :] = cosine_similarity(
            sentence_vectors[i].reshape(1, -1), sentence_vectors.reshape(num_sentences, -1)
        )
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
        for j in range(len(sentences)):
            if i == j:
              sim_mat[i][j] = 0
    nx_graph = nx.from_numpy_array(sim_mat)
    scores = nx.pagerank(nx_graph, max_iter=600, tol=1.0e-3)
    ranked_sentences = sorted(((scores[i],s) for i,s in enumerate(sentences)), reverse=True)
```

Longformer extract

```
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096")
def model_init():
    return LongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(       
        "allenai/longformer-base-4096", num_labels=2, id2label=id2label, label2id=label2id
    ).to(device)
trainer = Trainer(
    model_init=model_init,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_ds['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_ds['validation'],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

Comment: How do you create the sample of 1000 sample rows? Does the sample contain examples from both classes, 0 and 1?